# What method is best use to solve an ODE of this form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ {dx\over dt} = -[{1\over 8} e^{1-t\over 2}]   -{x\over 2}$$

So on the RHS I have a function of t - the exponential and a function of x.

Would the linear equation methods be a good choice?

Comment: Don't be fooled by how it looks... you should try a solution like $x=A t e^{-t/2}$ since the forcing term in square brackets causes resonance.

Comment: Maybe it would help to re-write the equation as $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{x}{2} = -\frac{1}{8}e^{1/2}e^{-t/2}$ and use the standard techniques.

Comment: What is the meaning of $$[…]$$?

Comment: The usual solution method works for any integrable function of $t$ on the RHS. Even if we read it as containing a floor function.

Answer (score 0):

$$ {dx\over dt} = -[{1\over 8} e^{1-t\over 2}]   -{x\over 2}$$
Let $a=-[{1\over 8} e^{1\over 2}] $
$$ {x\over 2}+{dx\over dt} = a\: e^{t\over 2}   $$
This is a usual form of linear first order ODE, non-homogeneous.

I suppose that you are familiar with solving this kind of ODE.

For example, solve the associated homogeneous PDE  $ {x\over 2}+{dx\over dt} =0$ . The general solution is $x_h=c_1\,e^{-t/2}$ . Then with a method such as the "variation of parameters' find a particular solution of the non-homogeneous ODE $x_p=-a\;x\;e^{-t/2}$ . The solution is $x(t)=x_h+x_p$ .

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is a meaningless qualifier as long as you don't specify a criterion.

There are essentially two approaches to solve the first order ODE's: finding an integrating factor or trying an ansatz.

In the case on hand, you have a linear equation with contant coefficients, so that

- you immediately have an ansatz of the homogeneous solution given by the characteristic equation;
- this ansatz is also an integrating factor.

Indeed, the characteristic polynomial is

$$\lambda+\frac12,$$ giving the homogeneous solution

$$e^{-t/2}.$$

Then dividing by this function,

$$\frac{e^{t/2}}2dt+e^{t/2}dx=d(e^{t/2}x)=-\frac{e^{(1-t)/2}}8e^{t/2}dt=-\frac e8dt$$ and by integration

$$e^{t/2}x=C-\frac e8t$$ and $$x=\left(C-\frac e8t\right)e^{-t/2}.$$